# How can I have multiple post handlers in the same asp razor page?

Tags: asp.net, http, post, asp.net-core

I'm making a forum where people can make two types of posts. How can I have my Reply page respond to POST requests based on parameters sent?

I've tried making each function have different parameters taken in but it doesn't make a difference. The only way I had them be called was to name them both `OnPost`. Now it gives me this error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:`

Which doesn't make sense since I'm sending `(int, string, string, string)` and the handlers are:

`OnPost(Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String)`

`OnPost(Int32, Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String)`

Comment: why are you sending parameters like that instead of creating an json, xml or custom content type?

Answer (score 0):

I simply did `@page "{handler?}"` at the top of the reply page, renamed each handler to `OnPostHandler` where Handler is any other name, and made the form action be `"Reply/Handler"`

Comment: FWIW, you can use the tag helper to gen the URL, using the `asp-page-handler` attribute: `<form asp-page-handler="Handler">`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have two post methods with the same name. You could rename one of them and use javascript to make a custom request.